# How do I check if a package is available for install?

Tags: installation, package-management

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Amazon EC2 instance along with Tomcat and MySql. Tomcat, Java and MySql packages were available along with Ubuntu and I didn't have to download them.

Now I wish to install Percona Xtrabackup to my Server.

Now, how do I find if a certain package is already available with the installation or I have to install it externally?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
apt-cache search <name>
```

Will give you a list of available packages matching the name.

Comment: Is there a way to check a long list of packages with single command?

Comment: Single command, not that I know of, in a single line it is possible using `echo <list> | xargs -L1 apt-cache search`